# ManyToMany slow in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have two simple models:

```
class A(models.Model):
name_a = models.CharField(
    _("name_a"),
    max_length=255)

    b = models.ManyToManyField(
        'B',
        related_name='a',
        blank=True
    )

class B(models.Model):
    name_b = models.CharField(
        _("name_b"),
        max_length=255)
```

I created 1000 records for A:

```
for i in range(1000):
    A.objects.create()
```

and 3 objects for B:

```
for i in range(3):
    B.objects.create()
```

and connect each Object of b with each object of a through the m2m relation:

```
for a in A.objects.all().iterator(): 
    a.b.add(B.objects.all()[0]) 
    a.b.add(B.objects.all()[1]) 
    a.b.add(B.objects.all()[2])
```

Now for each a object, I want to get all b objects:

```
import time 
start = time.time()
objects = A.objects.all()
for n in objects.iterator(): 
     list(n.b.all())
print(time.time() - start)

Output: 2.642864465713501
```

So it takes over 2 seconds for this query for just 1000 a objects. The performance is horrible. I have over 1000000 a objects in production.

I tried to increase the performance by using prefetch_related:

```
import time 
start = time.time()
objects = A.objects.all().prefetch_related('b')
for n in objects.iterator(): 
     list(n.b.all())
print(time.time() - start)

Output: 2.684298038482666
```

But that helps nothing. Why is it so slow and how can I improve the performance?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your actual problem, but maybe your `related_name` should be `'a'` rather than `'b'`.

Comment: Sharp eyes ;-) Thanks fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running this I'm around 0.7 sec with sqlite. Time reduces by 50% if I omit the list creation for every query.

Point is that you hit the DB as many times as you have `A` objects.
So the best bet for performance increase is reducing the number of queries you make.
But here it actually matters what exactly you intend to do.
As this in unclear, from here on it's more or less just guessing what could work for you...

Maybe just iterate through `A.objects.values_list('id')` and query `B` instead as you don't really use the `a` objects:

```
bq = B.objects.all()
for a_id, in A.objects.values_list('id').iterator():
    list(bq.filter(b__id=a_id))  # maybe correct your related_name to 'a' so this would look a__id=a_id
print(time.time() - start)
```

or

```
start = time.time()
a_ids = A.objects.values_list('id').all()
bq = B.objects.all()
[list(bq.filter(b__id=a_id)) for a_id, in a_ids]
print(time.time() - start)
```

If you just want all `b` objects related to some of your `a` objects, say, for example, all with `name_a` contains `'foo'`:

```
B.objects.filter(b__name_a__contains='foo').all().distinct()
```

*Hope these suggestions might help*

Comment: You are right, I didn't make my intend clear. I need to serialize the A and B objects. So I need an ASerializer class. I think a serializer also just loops over all A Objects like my code above and serializes them. And I found out that a serializer.data call also takes more than 2 seconds. So I just wanted to debug this by making the database calls by hand (using python's list method).

Answer (score 0):

From the Django docs for [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

> Note that if you use iterator() to run the query, prefetch_related() calls will be ignored since these two optimizations do not make sense together.